# Convert ssh public keys from various formats to Open SSH with node-forge

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, openssh, forge

I'd like to convert ssh public keys provided in various formats into the Open SSH format using node-forge.

I have no problem generating the keys and converting with:

```
forge.ssh.publicKeyToOpenSSH(key, comment);
```

but cannot figure out how to read the files into node-forge, Tried:

```
pki.publicKeyFromPem(pem);
```

or

```
pki.publicKeyFromAsn1(subjectPublicKeyInfo);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load `OpenSSL public keys (PKCS#8)` like this:

```
var forgePubKey = forge.pki.publicKeyFromPem('-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----' + publicKey + '-----END PUBLIC KEY-----');
```

where publicKey is `BASE64` encoded